# Syntax error with specific argument order

Tags: ruby, hash, syntax, literals

With this code:

```
Sponsorship.includes(patient: :vaccinations, :backer)
```

I get `syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>`. But when I change the order of the arguments like so:

```
Sponsorship.includes(:backer, patient: :vaccinations)
```

The errors go away. Why is the syntax error dependent on the order of the arguments?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: He got a syntax error and wants to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two valid alternatives here:

```
@sponsorship = Sponsorship.includes({ patient: :vaccinations }, :backer)
                      .find_by_slug(params[:id])

@sponsorship = Sponsorship.includes(:backer, patient: :vaccinations)
                      .find_by_slug(params[:id])
```

The first time you have 2 arguments, the first is an hash, and the second is a value,

In the second example you still have 2 arguments, the first is the value, and the second is an implicit hash. In ruby you can omit the brackets when the hash is the last argument passed to a method

What you did here:

```
@sponsorship = Sponsorship.includes(patient: :vaccinations, :backer)
                      .find_by_slug(params[:id])
```

Is interpreted as:

```
@sponsorship = Sponsorship.includes({ patient: :vaccinations, :backer })
                      .find_by_slug(params[:id])
```

Which is clearly wrong as hashes needs a `{ key0: value0, keyN: valueN }` syntax.

Comment: Awesome explanation! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Because a hash parameter needs to be the last parameter if you're relying on Ruby syntax sugar to avoid writing the `{}` yourself.

Comment: If I were to keep the order of the parameters, how would I fix the line causing the error? I think someone commented such a solution but deleted it.

Answer (score -1):

That's not valid ruby syntax.  You probably meant:

`@sponsorship = Sponsorship.includes(patient: [:vaccinations, :backer]).find_by_slug(params[:id])`

Note that `patient:` is the same as `:patient =>`, which is the key protion of a hash.  So ruby is expecting the next thing to be the value half of the hash, not a list of things.  I changed it to an array (not sure if that's what you meant).

Comment: Not exactly what I meant. In your suggestion, you imply that sponsorship has one patient, patient has many vaccinations, and patient has one backer, which isn't the case. It really is sponsorship has one patient, patient has many vaccinations, and sponsorship has one backer.

Answer (score -1):

The `includes` method expects to find the hash as the last argument. You must pass the hash as such. Otherwise you must put `{}` around the hash.

Comment: If that is the sole reason, it would raise an argument error, not a syntax error. Your explanation is thus irrelevant.

Comment: Its a syntax error because the hash as the first argument requires the curly braces to be syntactically accurate.

Answer (score -1):

```
@sponsorship = Sponsorship.includes(:backer, patient: [:vaccinations]).find_by_slug(params[:id])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.